# How to setup Keda authentication with GCP PubSub when deployments are using workload identity in GCP?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-pubsub, keda

I'm stuck setting up [Keda](https://keda.sh) in my private GKE cluster, with Google PubSub Scaler.

I have a deployment what I would like to scale based on the number of messages in a subscription. My deployment is accessing Google resources (poll a subscription) through [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)

My current setup is something like this.

My deployment: (just added the relevant parts):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: delay-executor
  name: delay-executor
  namespace: workflows
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: delay-executor-sa
      automountServiceAccountToken: false
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 70
```

The service account yaml looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: delay-executor-sa@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  name: delay-executor-sa
  namespace: workflows
```

this service account has the roles: `roles/pubsub.publisher`, `roles/pubsub.subscriber` and `roles/monitoring.viewer`.

Now comes the keda part.

I thought I should use TriggerAuthenticator with podIdentity set to `gcp`, this is my setup:

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: keda-trigger-auth-gcp-credentials
  namespace: workflows
spec:
  podIdentity:
    provider: gcp
```

And my ScaledObject yaml:

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: delay-executor-pubsub-scaledobject
  namespace: workflows
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: delay-executor
  triggers:
  - type: gcp-pubsub
    authenticationRef:
      name: keda-trigger-auth-gcp-credentials
    metadata:
      subscriptionSize: "5"
      subscriptionName: "my-subscription"
```

After applying these settings, my deployment scales down to zero, however in the subscriptions there are many messages, checking the logs of `keda-operator` I found errors like this:

```
ERROR controller Reconciler error {"reconcilerGroup": "keda.sh", "reconcilerKind": "ScaledObject", "controller": "scaledobject", "name": "delay-executor-pubsub-scaledobject", "namespace": "workflows", "error": "error getting scaler for trigger #0: error parsing PubSub metadata: GoogleApplicationCredentials not found"}
```

and

```
ERROR   gcp_pub_sub_scaler  error getting Active Status {"error": "unexpected end of JSON input"}
```

The Pod works as expected, can pull from the subscription.

So There are two things here,

1. I have an authentication issue, and I'm curious how a working setup looks like?
2. Why the deployment is scaled down to zero, in case of broken authentication?

Thanks

Comment: Turned out it's not yet implemented.

Comment: They have "Pod Identity" listed on https://keda.sh/docs/1.4/concepts/authentication/ but no support for Google Workload Identity. You might be able to add support yourself by doing something similar to https://github.com/kedacore/keda/pull/275/files.

Comment: Feature request is open on https://github.com/kedacore/keda/issues/2048